# Call Sub within a Sub in Outlook - Autofilter Method of Range Class failed

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

The code below calls a sub (macro) within another sub.

When calling the second Sub "Universal_Dry_Good(sheet) it runs until

```
sheet.Range("$B$2:$X$21200").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="**TUN**", Operator:=xlFilterValues
```

"Universal_Dry_Good" runs fine on its own inside Excel. It is just when I am calling it inside another macro that it fails.

Goal: When Sub Cat() runs, it opens an Excel file and then runs "Universal Dry Good" on the specified Excel file/sheet. These macros live inside Outlook, and are triggered off incoming emails.

Why once "Universal Dry Good" is called does it no longer work?

The error is

> Autofilter Method of Range Class failed

It does work independently, also when replaced with other actions (e.g. `Columns.Replace`, `Rows.Delete` etc.).

```
Sub Universal_Dry_Good(sheet)
'
' Universal_Dry_Good Macro
'
    sheet.Rows("1:3").Delete
    sheet.Rows("1:3").Delete Shift:=xlUp
    'ERROR IN THE LINE BELOW
    sheet.Range("$B$2:$X$21200").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="**TUN**", _
        Operator:=xlFilterValues
    sheet.Range("B3:C3").Select
    sheet.Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    sheet.Range("B3:AA10000").Select
    Selection.EntireRow.Delete
    sheet.Rows("2:2").Select
    sheet.ActiveSheet.ShowAllData
    Selection.AutoFilter
End Sub

Sub Cat()
    Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    xlApp.Application.Visible = True
    xlApp.Workbooks.Open "---------"
    Dim sheet As Object
    Set sheet = xlApp.Worksheets("Report 1")

    Universal_Dry_Good sheet
End Sub
```

Comment: Is this Universal_Dry_Good on the Excel file or on Outlook?

Comment: The line in question is also missing the underscore _ at the end before breaking the line.

Comment: @RicardoA - Universal_Dry_Good is in Outlook

Comment: @RicardoA same error returned after trying your recommended edits ( understanding the _ was the main materially different adjustment and it was mainly meant for cosmetics for trouble shooting, but I did want to let you know I appreciate the recommended edits and I tried them)

Comment: I just created a test file and i was having the same problem. Removing Operator:=xlFilterValues fixed it for me. If you remove that option, do you get the outcome you are looking for?

Comment: @RicardoA No, I get an error two lines below at [ sheet.Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select   ] . I would like to note that I copied the Universal_Dry_Good(Sheet) Macro  into the Outlook IDE from my excel IDE, but I changed it slightly because I had to add ".sheet" before the actions and thought there was extra code and thought there was unnecessary code from "record macro" features (additional clicks ect) Please view the original code that works & lives in my excel workbook. As I am sure you understand, I am trying to call this from my Sub Cat() macro (all inside outlk)

Comment: Sub Universal_Dry_Good()
       Rows("1:3").Select
        Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
        Rows("1:1").Select
    Selection.AutoFilter
    Range("B2:C2").Select
    ActiveSheet.Range("$B$2:$X$21200").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="**TUN**", Operator:=xlFilterValues
    Range("B3:C3").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Range("B3:AA10000").Select
    Selection.EntireRow.Delete
    Rows("2:2").Select
    ActiveSheet.ShowAllData
    Selection.AutoFilter

Comment: (cont..)Dim workbook_Name As Variant
workbook_Name = Application.GetSaveAsFilename
If workbook_Name <> False Then
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=workbook_Name
End If
End Sub

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code below solved: Thank you for all your help @RicardoA:

```
Sub Universal_Dry_Good(sheet)
'
' Universal_Dry_Good Macro
'

sheet.Application.DisplayAlerts = False

sheet.Rows("1:3").Delete

sheet.Rows("1:1").Select

sheet.Range("B2:C2").Select

sheet.Range("$B$2:$X$21200").Autofilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="**TUN**"

sheet.Range("B3:C3").Select


sheet.Range("B3:AA10000").Delete
sheet.Rows("2:2").Select
sheet.ShowAllData
sheet.Cells.Autofilter


sheet.Application.DisplayAlerts = True


End Sub


Sub Pat()
Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
xlApp.Application.Visible = True
xlApp.Workbooks.Open "--------"
Dim sheet As Object
 Set sheet = xlApp.Worksheets("Report 1")


Universal_Dry_Good sheet

 End Sub
```